# Memory access exception when using XMVECTOR

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I'm making pong in DirectX11 and I'm getting some weird error.

I have a pointer declared inside my `Pong` class:

```
XMVECTOR *ballDirection;
```

And for some reason, whenever I try to access it:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x002127d8 in DirectX11Pong.exe:
  0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I'm pretty sure this is what happens when you try to access a `nullptr` pointer, but, 
before any "accessing" to the pointer happens, I have it initialized:

```
ballDirection = new XMVECTOR();
```

For example, the line of code right now I'm getting this error at is the following:

```
*ballDirection = XMVectorSetX(*ballDirection, 1);
```

The only other information that I think is relevant is that I tried earlier to turn a single pointer that holds the paddle info into an array of pointers (for multiple players):

(Before)

```
Sprite *paddle;
```

(After)

```
Sprite *paddle[2];
```

The moment I did this, I got this error accessing `ballDirection`,
even though it worked perfectly before I made this array, and I changed no code to do with `ballDirection` while creating the array and modifying the appropriate code.

After I noticed getting this error I changed the code back, and this still happened.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it completely against some unspoken creed you have to initialize your pointers to NULL on naked declarations? `Sprite *paddle = NULL;`. Get into that habit please.

Comment: Please make a testcase if you can! There is not enough here to know what you've done wrong.

Comment: "After I noticed getting this error I changed the code back, and this still happened."  Did you completely rebuild your project?

Comment: rebuild did not work :(, and sarcastic remark about set the pointer to NULL, i'm sorry, I'm a 14 year kid whos been learning c++ for 3 monthes off random crap on the internet. Dont hate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft does [say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418725%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about dynamic allocation of `XMVECTOR` that:

> Allocations from the heap, however, are more complicated. As such, you
>   need to be careful whenever you use either XMVECTOR or XMMATRIX as a
>   member of a class or structure to be allocated from the heap. 
>   On Windows x64, all heap allocations are 16-byte aligned, but for 
>   Windows x86, they are only 8-byte aligned.

So you should not just `new XMVECTOR` there and expect that all works.

Comment: Awesome! I chaned it to an XMFLOAT2 and made my own function to normalize vectors and it works fine now! Funny how the answer with no "likes" is the most clear one and the one that works, thanks so much :D

Comment: @Aaronman8 Your welcome. The answers that suggest you to debug your code are indeed more popular. My experience is that tricks of Microsoft are as often the cause of issues (and it is not easy to debug the closed source libs of Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

1. Always check your allocations! At least macro something noobish like that:

   ```
   #if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
   #ifndef XBOOL
       #define XBOOL(x)                                                                \
       {                                                                               \
           if(!(x))                                                                    \
           {                                                                           \
               MessageBox(0, L"Error running: "L#x, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);    \
               return false;                                                           \
           }                                                                           \
       }
   #endif
   #else
       #ifndef XBOOL
           #define XBOOL(x) (x);
       #endif
   #endif
   ```

Usage:

```
XBOOL(ballDirection = new XMVECTOR())
```

2. Use debugger! Set up some breakpoints, check pointer value from a place of allocation to place of error in every line.